# How to Convert Int Array to a single long value

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers

```
int[]values = {45,89,3000,719,1,90,167,18920};
```

How can I convert the above to a single `long`value in java.

So, I know that when working with byte arrays and we have the following

```
byte [] bytes = { 0, 6, 36, -84, 113, 125, -118, -47 };
```

I Can get the equivalent long value of the bytes above as

```
 long wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getLong();
 System.out.println(""+wrapped);
```

gives `1729172917291729`

So, is it possible to achieve the same using integer array instead of byte array?
Thanks all.

Comment: and ... what value is that supposed to be?

Comment: do you expect a long value which is **concatenated** of all elements of that array?

Comment: Just like when you are converting a byte array to a single long, I want something similar to that

Comment: just explain us how the output should be.

Comment: Can you give a real example, that is where we can understand the result from the input data.

Comment: Ok, simply put how can I convert an IntBuffer to a LongBuffer in java

Comment: don't try to "simply" put something, show us the output you expect for a specific input.

Comment: In your example with bytes, you gave an array of 8 bytes that can be compressed to a single long. You can compress 8 bytes to a long because a long is 8 bytes.
But what you want to do with int is impossible since an int is 4 bytes. You cannot compress 8 ints to a long, at best you could compress 2 ints to a long.

Comment: You could conceive a mapping from 8 ints to 1 long in the form of a hash code. However it is not possible to map this back to the original 8 ints.

Answer (score 2):

**It is impossible**.

`long` value store 64 bits. Which mean that it can hold only two `int` (which is 32 bits).

Comment: Yea, you are right in a way but have you used IntBuffers in java before now? Is there any way to convert an IntBuffer to a LongBuffer? The very essence of this is to compress the int array into a distinct long value and vice versa